# How to Set a default value for column filter in primeng table

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to set the default value for `primeNg` table column and it's not working, below is my code, appreciate your help on this.

I have tried to add filter and set default value with `filterValue="#{this.defaultFilterValue}"`

```
<p-dataTable id="empTable" [lazy]="false" [(value)]="CSETEmps" [editable]="true" editMode="row" [responsive]="true"
    [resizableColumns]="false" [style]="{'margin-top':'5px'}" [tableStyle]="{'table-layout':'auto'}" [rows]="30"
    [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[30,60,90]" var="data" (onclick)="onTableClick($event)"
    (onchange)="onTableChange($event)" #dt>
```

I expect the filter default value has to be set as 'Active' but it's not

Comment: are you using dropdown or search filter on column?

Comment: You should elevorate a little more and put an example in stackblitz. `p-dataTable` doesn't have a property called `filterValue`. Another note is that `p-dataTable` is depecrated and you should use `p-table` instead. For the information in the filters of `p-dataTable` you have the examples in the primeng webpage: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/filter